# Silverlight Project Not Updating When Ran

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010

I'm currently developing with VS2010 RC and Silverlight 4 and ran into small problem. My project when ran, would show a version I had built about 4 hours ago. (I built the project using the Business Template) The project itself will not update, meaning all the forms, and controls.

I did the following:

- Restarted my computer
- Restarted Visual Studio
- Deleted the xap file in the **ClientBin** folder on the web side
- Deleted the **Generated_Code** folder on the client side
- Deleted the xap file from the **Debug** folder on the client side
- Opened the Solution's **Configuration Manager** and ensuring both my web and client projects are checked.
- Rebuilt, built, and cleaned every combination of the different projects and solution
- Deleted and re-added the project in the MTT.Web properties

Is there a known bug or something else I can try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few of things you might try:

1) Clear your cached/temporary internet files in your browser.

2) Make each url to the XAP unique to prevent client side caching. One technique using the Page class in ASP.NET:

```
<param name="source" value="<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/ClientBin/YourApp.xap?x=" + (new Random()).Next(1000000)) %>" />
```

For more see: [Avoid incorrect Silverlight XAP file caching](http://codeblog.larsholm.net/2010/02/avoid-incorrect-caching-of-silverlight-xap-file/)

3) Are you using a proxy server? Is there caching on the proxy server? The above method should prevent proxy server caching.